# Javascript split by square brackets and numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, split

How can I use the js split function to split a string by a closing square bracket character (`]`) as well as numbers, '1' '2' '3' etc?

I tried this:

```
text.split(/[\\[123456789]/);
```

but it's not splitting correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this regex: `/\]|\d+/`

Example below:

```js
string = 'example] with 0.. 12.. 3.. some] numbers 1232';
document.body.innerHTML = string.split(/\]|\d+/).join`<br>`;
```

Explaining:

```
\]      # literal ']' character
|       # OR
\d+     # any number
```

If you want to split by each digit instead of the whole number just remove the plus `+` sign. The `+` plus sign is there just to match `\d` digits in group.

Comment: Any further problem like this, feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = 'all1the2words3you]need';
console.log(str.split(/[\d\]]/)); //["all", "the", "words", "you", "need"]
```